# correct way to get $wpdb object in custom plugin file

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to have a correct way to get $wpdb object in a custom file under `XYZ_Plugin`.
Thing to keep in mind is that the user can access that page directly by URL.
it means No `if(!defined('ABSPATH')) exit();` check.
Actually, I want users to download the file by fileId and they can make request to download like this

```
http://www.website.com/wp-content/plugins/DOWNLOAD_FILE/download.php?fileId=45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you are loading this file from. If its in your plugin folder (DOWNLOAD_FILE) like you said, you are looking to add something like this to the top of your code.

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

Once that is added you can go ahead and call the $wpdb globals and use all of wordpress's functions.

Comment: you don't need to add these two files `wp-load.php` and `wp-includes/wp-db.php` only `wp-config.php` will do everything for you.